# Different MySQL syntax errors in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple `INSERT INTO` query which fails every time. The strange thing is, if I take out the column the error points to initially, or the one before that, I just get a different error.

This is the query:

```
mysql_query("insert into list_items
 (list_id,position,item,small_image,large_image,asin,description,
  author,publish_date,amazon_description) values  
 ('$id','$key','$value','$small_image','$large_image','$asin',
  '$descriptions[$key]','$authors[$key]','$publish_date','$amazon_description')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

The sample data I'm using is:

```
$key=1;
$value=mysql_real_escape_string("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone");
$small_image="some_image_url";
$large_image="some_image_url";
$asin="13412341234";
$descriptions[$key]="";
$authors[$key]="JK Rowling";
$publish_date="1999-09-08";
$amazon_description=mysql_real_escape_string($long_amazon_description);
```

The error I get is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1999-09-08')' at line 1

When I remove the 'publish_date' column from the query I get a different error, saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''','')' at line 1

So I figured it must have something to do with the 'author' column so I removed that too, leaving this query:

```
mysql_query("insert into list_items 
 (list_id,position,item,small_image,large_image,
  asin,description,amazon_description) values 
 ('$id','$key','$value','$small_image','$large_image',
 '$asin','$descriptions[$key]','$amazon_description') ")
or die(mysql_error());
```

...but I got the same error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `item_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `voted_up` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voted_down` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `small_image` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `large_image` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `publish_date` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `amazon_description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=379 ;
```

The query prints out as:

```
insert into list_items
(list_id,position,item,small_image,large_image,asin,description,
author,publish_date,amazon_description) values
('76','1','Harry Potter And The Sorcerer\'s Stone',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MU5VilKpL._SL160_.jpg',
 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MU5VilKpL.jpg','059035342X','',
 'J.K. Rowling','1999-09-08',
 'Harry Potter has no idea how famous he is. That\'s because he\'s being raised by his miserable aunt and uncle who are terrified Harry will learn that he\'s really a wizard, just as his parents were. But everything changes when Harry is summoned to attend an infamous school for wizards, and he begins to discover some clues about his illustrious birthright. From the surprising way he is greeted by a lovable giant, to the unique curriculum and colorful faculty at his unusual school, Harry finds himself drawn deep inside a mystical world he never knew existed and closer to his own noble destiny.')
```

IMPORTANT EDIT:

When the query is reduced to `insert into list_items (list_id,position) values ('82','1')` it still fails, which is completely inexplicable to me.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string($long_amazon_description")` <-- why do you have a `"` in there?

Comment: That's a typo, sorry, it's not like that in the original code.

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: Please assign your SQL to a variable before executing it.  You can then output it to see exactly what is being passed to `mysql_query()`.  My guess is that string quoting has gone wrong somewhere...

Comment: @eggyal Done, added it to the end of the question. Can't see what the problem is looking at the query as it was printed out.

Comment: Its saying it doesnt like your date. I always formatted mine as "m/d/Y"

Comment: Might one of your variables contain an unexpected non-printable character that isn't showing in your output?  As an aside (to both you and @BugFinder) one really ought to store dates in a [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html)-type column, rather than a string-type; if in a string, `Ymd` is better than `mdY` since lexicographic ordering is semantically meaningful.

Comment: When I try your printed query on my MySQL server **it worked normally**. Have you tried, for example, using phpMyAdmin to execute your SQL?

Comment: @Alvin It works for me in phpMyAdmin too. In PHP, it doesn't work even if I reduce the query to this: insert into list_items (list_id,position) values ('81','1') You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''','')' at line 1

Comment: @eggyal, Good point. I didnt spot he stored it as string - I always stored mine as a date!

Comment: Thanks for the date advice, but the date apparently has nothing to do with it (see my comment above).

Comment: @BugFinder: Then how do you store dates as `mdY`?  MySQL expects [date literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html) to be `Ymd`.

Comment: don't put apostrophes around int variables in the query! so like insert into .. ... values ($id, $key ... '$author')

Comment: Can we please not digress into discussing date formats here?

Comment: @eggyal Yes, but since the query fails even when I reduce it to `insert into list_items (list_id,position) values ('81','1')`, I don't think that should be the problem...also, the full query works in phpMyAdmin but not from PHP directly.

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to emphasise that point.  I'm stumped!

Comment: for your short test "insert into list_items (list_id,position) values ('81','1')" do it without simple quotes for int type and should be `insert into list_items (list_id,position) values (81,1)`

Comment: Edited...I'm completely lost too, I mean what could be going wrong when I'm just inserting two INTs into two INT columns?!

Comment: @khaled Same error when I try without the quotes around INTs, I tried already...

Comment: remove quotes from '76','1'... INT should not be quoted....

Comment: And now the original query works without changing anything?! I have no idea what's going on. I just brought back the original code and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping these

```
$small_image="some_image_url";
$large_image="some_image_url";
```

before including in your query

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is here:

```
... values ('$id','$key','$value','$small_image','$large_image',
 '$asin','$descriptions[$key]','$amazon_description') ")
```

around the variables that are arrays, you need to have curly braces `{}`.

eg:

```
 '{$descriptions[$key]}','{$authors[$key]}'
```

This is because **PHP** will understand what you are typing. so when you echo this out, it will echo out the contents of the array as you'd expect. But **SQL** will not.

Comment: $descriptions[$key] is just a string by the time it reaches MySQL. Also, the query fails whatever I put there, and even if I remove that part completely.

Comment: As far as I knew, not for quoted keys. See php.net ref: `http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex`

Comment: btw have you checked all syntax types in the database? eg. if `null` is the auto field value, `NOT NULL` must be unticked aswell in the database GUI. I've had a similar issue before because of that.